# Connect Java Desktop App with Socket.io

Tags: java, node.js, javafx, websocket, socket.io

How can I connect my Java Desktop application to my SocketIO server. I have a Node.js server with socket.io and i try to connect my web with a desktop app but all the libraries on internet are for android, and I need for JavaFX or Java Swing

do you know some ones? because if i use a WS:// protocol i can´t get the handshake
Sorry for my english :D

Comment: Have you tried this => https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

Comment: yes but this is for android? because i can't run the library u,u

Comment: It is a Java client, which can also be used in Android. So I think you should give it a try/

Comment: Two more

1) https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
2) http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

Hope they help. :)

Comment: do you know if the example project is in NetBeans,  because i use eclipse and i not understand the folders in NetBeans